# Git remove same file with different capitalization

Tags: git

Because of some necessities, I've changed `.git/config` `ignorecase = false` in order to make case sensitive. Then rename file from upper case to lower case. For example, I renamed `Account_Model.php` to `Account_model.php` manually, even other branches.

By the different case, git makes the `Uncommitted changes`, then I committed the new files with lower case (git assume the lower case new files).

Now I'm in trouble. I pull the repo for the server where to have deployments, the directory creates 2 files. One is `Account_model.php` (What I want) and the other is `Account_Model.php`.

They became separate two files! But turn back to my local, I only see 1 file in the directory. (Because of the one, I cannot delete the upper case one)

If I change some of them, the two file with different cases will alert at the same time. The diff shows the same modifies.

[image: Two file with same diff]

But I only can see only one in the directory.

[image: Only 1 file in the directory]

I cannot delete the upper case one. (If could, I think the lower case one would be delete too.

There's a way can change case by the command. I know, I chose the wrong way.

So how can I deal with that two case files, and keep the changes (only one file with lower case) forever?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OS X's filesystem is, by default, case-insensitive. So if you have two files in a Git repository with the same name but different cases you get the problem you're having now.

A simple work around is to use Disk Utility to create a case-sensitive disk image, clone the repo onto that, fix the problem there, and push the fix.

To make the disk image...

- Open Disk Utility.
- Do File -> New Image -> Blank Image.
- Set the Format to be OS X Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled).

[image]

It will automatically be mounted and waiting for you in `/Volumes`. After you clone you should see both files and can do with them as you please.

Comment: Okay! I finally followed your way, created a disk image (then can see files with different capitalizations), cloned all files, removed files with lower case, renamed it from upper case to lower case, and pushed them. Thank you for that. <3