# EGit not ignoring case insensitive deletion

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

My company maintains a large project through Git and a while back, someone managed to push a folder containing both `file1.sql` and `file1.SQL`.
I guess the repo is case sensitive, so it allowed it. However, my mac is case insensitive, so it will only allow me to have one (I have the one with the lowercase extension).

Thus my problem: locally, `git status` showed that I had deleted the file with the uppercase extension. This was fixed by running `git checkout -- file1.SQL`. But in Eclipse, EGit still shows the file deletion as an unstaged change. The option to ignore does not show up when I right click the file in the Unstaged Changes window.

Does anyone know how to make EGit also ignore this "file deletion"?

Comment: minor: you have sensitive/insensitive reversed here: if creating READ.ME and then opening read.me works, the file system is case-insensitive, but if READ.ME and read.me are two different files, the file system is case-sensitive. Git *internally* is always case sensitive (except for some branch and tag name issues) as file data is stored under hash names, and file names are stored in "tree" objects under more hash names, so that everything is just data. All that aside, I have no idea how to make *E*-Git behave.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to step out of EGit for a minute, and [mount a case-sensitive volume on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40494914/6309)

In that volume, you can easily `git rm file1.sql`, add it to your .gitignore (to avoid adding it again by mistake) and commit.

Once that is done, and `git status` is clear, you can open Eclipse again.

Comment: Unfortunately my work computer is pretty restricted so I can't create new disk images. At one point I merged a branch that deleted the uppercase file, so only the lowercase one would remain in the repo. After on master locally, everything was fine. But then someone else still had the uppercase version locally and when they merged their branch, it added it back. Preventing this would require coordination across hundreds of developers which sadly won't happen.

But `git status` is clear currently. I just don't get why that is not reflected in Eclipse.

Comment: @Bryan Yes, preventing that means a pre-receive hook on the server side, that way you don't need to coordinate all clients.